on demand AWS Fargate containers
I had 2 doubts about using AWS Fargate (as the docs+any blogs are shit and confusing)

What if I run a task(web app) 24/7 I'll be charged for the whole period right? Also, will it charge based on the amount of resources allocated or only the amount of resources utilized?

How do I turn this container to shut down when not required? (kinda like hibernating if inactivity or not having any utilization of resources.. so that I save up on the cost) and use only when needed? I'm okay with the cold start.
Is something like this(on demand containers kinda :D) possible or the solution is to migrate the whole app to serverless(lambdas) if that's the case


As the app doesn't have users 24/7 but is more of an once in a while need
Tried reading up on it on various different blogs and the AWS docs but couldn't get it

Note that, depending on your definition of "web app" a Lambda may be a pretty poor browser based experience.  If you host the static portion of your site in S3 and the backend stuff in Lambda you're ok but trying to serve HTML/CSS/etc from Lamda doesn't work well.


What if I run a task(web app) 24/7 I'll be charged for the whole period right?

That is correct

Also, will it charge based on the amount of resources allocated or only the amount of resources utilized?

Allocated. You are reserving that much underlying hardware that no other AWS customer can use during that time, so you pay for the hardware that is allocated, regardless of how much you actually use it.

How do I turn this container to shut down when not required?

ECS doesn't support this usage pattern. When a request comes in, if there is no ECS task ready to process the request then the load balancer will simply return an error code.
AWS AppRunner does support this. It will do something similar to hibernation for your running container. During that time you are still charged for memory usage, but you will not be charged for CPU usage.

possible or the solution is to migrate the whole app to serverless(lambdas)

That's probably going to be the cheapest way to run your app on AWS, since Lambda is the only service will not charge you at all when there are no requests, while still being able to start-up and process requests when they come in.
